# Should I update my nvidia drivers on Ubuntu if I don't want to have any issues with Pytorch or Tensorflow?

Tags: ubuntu, pytorch, driver, nvidia

I have recently set up environment for pytorch on fresh Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS system.

My current package versions:

```
nvidia drivers: 520.61.05
CUDA version: 11.8
pytorch: 2.0.1+cu118
```

It seems that there are [some compatibility issues](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-for-cuda-12/169447) between [latest pytorch update](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) and latest CUDA Toolkit 12. Furthermore, it seems that CUDA 12.8 (latest) is incompatible with nvidia drivers v520.61.05 and CUDA 11.8 is incompatible with nvidia drivers v535.54.03 (latest) according to Table 3 from [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#:%7E:text=The%20CUDA%20driver%20maintains%20backward,within%20the%20corresponding%20major%20release.) page.

Now I want to run `sudo apt-get update` but it seems that it would update my nvidia drivers and (or) CUDA toolkit and pytorch won't work properly with CUDA.

Should I add nvidia drivers and CUDA toolkit to the blacklist for updates? If so, how should I do that? What is a good approach to manage the versions of these packages?